# How do I track Yahoo Adwords campaigns in Google Analytics with cost data?

Tags: google-analytics, advertising, yahoo

I'm currently diving into Yahoo's adwords program and am wondering if its possible to track their ad campaigns in Google Analytics with cost data so I can trace my costs to my revenue. Has anyone accomplished this or know a good way to do it?

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this[1] solution still works (The post is from 2008). If not, take a look at the Google Analytics Help sites. You can track almost everything. If the solution in the link fails, you maybe just have to set correct URL' and/or patterns. It's a while ago when i've done something similar. with DoubleClick (that was before google bought it.. ;-))

[1] http://www.ppchero.com/the-secret-of-tracking-yahoo-keyword-data-in-google-analytics/

Comment: Thanks this is useful. I think I'm asking for something that currently isn't possible, and that's tracking cost data as well, so I don't have to flip back and forth between analytics and Yahoo's web panel. That's OK, this will do.